# How to copy and set a row of data into another sheet if a string condition is met in a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to create a Submit sheet that has 42 rows. They have a border around it indicating where I type my data in. My goal is once Submit is typed in at the end of the row it'll paste that row of data into the bottom of my Database sheet

Here is the code ive been writing and having problems with. Sorry if it looks whacky I'm rookie at this

```js
function submit1(){
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 
 
var colVal = "Submit";
var colToSearch = 19; 
var dataRangeVals = range.getValues();


 for(var i = dataRangeVals.length; i <= 173; i++){
    if([i][colToSearch] === colVal){
      var sourceVal =  sheet.getRow(i+[colToSearch]).getValues(); 
      Logger.log(sourceVal);

      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase");
      var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
      targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,18).setValues(sourceVal);

    };
  };
};
```

the var dataRangeVals works and gets all the values of my submit sheet, but when I iterate through it and log sourceVal to check if it grabbed the row of data when I typed Submit into Column T
[image]

No values show in the execution log which is probably why nothing gets pasted into my DataBase sheet but it still shows execution complete without any errors which is confusing me . The problem is I don't understand why that's happening.

If you guys could help me out and take a look at it i'd greatly appreciate it.
Here is the link if you'd like it.
[Stock Database updated link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OFlTkYUapuwkesb73IQfSq83ROmkCtLWchqn0ElyVH0/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: Sample image]

Comment: Can't access the sample spreadsheet. Could you add screenshot instead?

Comment: I've updated the link so you can access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues:

1. `for(var i = dataRangeVals.length; i <= 173; i++){` will start at 131 and no data will be captured. Instead, replace it with `for(var i = 0; i < dataRangeVals.length; i++){`.
2. `[i][colToSearch]` wont return anything. To read the element of an array it should be dataRangeVals[i][colToSearch].
3. I tried to print the column T of your sheet and the **Submit** text has extra space in it. `if([i][colToSearch] === colVal){`  won't work because `Submit` is not equal to `Submit`  . Instead use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
4. `sheet.getRow(i+[colToSearch])` wont work because [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) has no getRow() method. Replace getRow() with [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

**Code:**

```
function submit1(){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  var colVal = "Submit";
  var colToSearch = 19; 
  var dataRangeVals = range.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < dataRangeVals.length; i++){
    if(dataRangeVals[i][colToSearch].toString().match(colVal)){
        var sourceVal = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 19).getValues();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase");
        var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
        sourceVal[0].splice(0,1)//remove the empty first element of subarray 
        
        targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,18).setValues(sourceVal);
      };
    };
};
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the pointer and help works great!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and found that on your IF condition `if([i][colToSearch] === colVal)`, the `[i][colToSearch]` has a `null` or `undefined` value as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmrfn.png) on the execution log result. Thus, your IF statement automatically ends the execution of your code and no values are shown.

I did some tweaks on your code to be able to proceed on the IF statement (to find if the last row matches the word "Submit") then copy the last row data from "[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOd1a.png)" to the "[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv3zk.png)" sheet's last row.

Please refer to my sample code here: **Updated**

```
function submit1(){
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase");
var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()+1;
 
var colVal = "Submit";
var colToSearch = 20; 
var dataRangeVals = range.getValues();

 for(var i = 1; i <= dataRangeVals.length; i++){//Loop to check column 20 with "Submit" value
    if(sheet.getRange(i,colToSearch).getValue().valueOf(colVal)){//Check each rows on column 20 to find ones that has "Submit" value
          for(var x = 2; x<=colToSearch-1; x++){//When a row has "Submit" value, it will get all row data and copies it to "DataBase" sheet
              var sourceVal = sheet.getRange(i,x).getValues();
              targetSheet.getRange(lastRow,x-1).setValues(sourceVal);
          }
          lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()+1;//Refreshes the new last row on "DataBase" sheet
          Logger.log("Done copying row data on \"Sheet\" Row #" + i + " to \"DataBase\"");
    }else{
      //Do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

After running the code, you will be able to see all of the data from the row on "Sheet", copied and added on every last row of the "Database" Sheet. You Should this sample execution log [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29S3f.png) once it is successful.

**Updated Result**

Here's my test spreadsheet, based on your spreadsheet design:

[image]

Here's the result on DataBase sheet:

[image]

Comment: Jay G thank you for taking the time to help! I tried your code on my mine but it didn't work I think the problem is I wrote the wrong value in my original code so you had the submit value in column S. My submit value is in column T, so I changed the colToSearch to 20 but it still didn't work. Ik your code works because I tested it on a new  spreadsheet, but on my original it wont. I've updated the permission in sheets if you'd like trouble shoot on the link.

Comment: Hi Zachary. I have updated my code above based on your sample spreadsheet design. The code will copy any row data to "DataBase" that has "Submit" value on column 20.

Comment: Thank you Jay for all the help works great!

Comment: is it possible to add on a simple on edit trigger to that function?

Comment: Yes, you can add the submit1() function to an onEdit trigger.